# Difference between UserDefaults() and UserDefaults.standard

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, swift3, userdefaults

Is there a difference between `UserDefaults()` and `UserDefaults.standard` in Swift 3.0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UserDefaults** - Gives you a `new object`, each object is allocated a different memory and deallocated when object scope is finished.

**UserDefaults.standard** - Gives you the `singleton` object by using the class method `standard` the object received by this method is allocated single memory throughout the application.

And the usage of them if you´re interesedted in that:

```
// Set
UserDefaults.standard.set("YOUR STRING", forKey: "key")
UserDefaults().set("YOUR STRING", forKey: "key")


// Get
UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "key")
UserDefaults().string(forKey: "key")
```

Comment: Yeah.. but from a practical standpoint, how are they different?

Answer (score 1):

```
let ud = UserDefault()
let uds = UserDefaults.standard
```

- Both objects will use the same underlying plist file to get/set
  values.
- Setting a value for a key with "ud" gives the same value
  using the "uds" object.

You can create and use instances of "UserDefault" created with the convenience "init" method, but the Foundation documentation encourages a developer to use the singleton accessible by the "standard" variable.